# Google map on page loaded by AJAX - how to initialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a google map to initialize on a page loaded by AJAX.

**Live test page (in dev):** http://dma.nz/practice/

The map is near the bottom of the page.

Currently it works - the map initializes when page it loaded directly or via AJAX, however it's giving me the following error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

In my footer I have:

```
<script src="/js/map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBpC5JE9ZmQduEXiGbiNxZsws8OLMiC-Bw&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script src="/js/init.js"></script>
```

map.js contains:

```
function initMap() {

  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 17,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.85855, 174.754944), 
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      styles: [
        {"featureType":"administrative",
        "elementType":"labels.text.fill",
        "stylers":[{"gamma":"0.00"},{"weight":"0.01"},{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"landscape",
        "elementType":"all",
        "stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"landscape.natural",
        "elementType":"geometry",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"landscape.natural.terrain",
        "elementType":"geometry.stroke",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"poi",
        "elementType":"all",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"road",
        "elementType":"all",
        "stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"32"},{"visibility":"on"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"road",
        "elementType":"labels.text",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"road.highway",
        "elementType":"all",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"road.highway",
        "elementType":"geometry",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":"63"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"road.highway",
        "elementType":"labels.text",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"road.highway",
        "elementType":"labels.icon",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"road.arterial",
        "elementType":"labels.icon",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"transit",
        "elementType":"all",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"transit.station",
        "elementType":"all",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]
        },
        {"featureType":"water",
        "elementType":"all",
        "stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#eeeeee"}]
        }
      ]
  };

  // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
  var mapElement = document.getElementById('google-map');

  // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

  // Add marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: '/img/icons/map-pin.svg',
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.858749, 174.754944),
    map: map,
    title: 'DMA'
  });
}
```

And then the related part of init.js

```
ajaxLoad = function(html) {
    init();
    // init google map
    initMap();
    // change html title
    var HTMLtitle = $(".content > section:first-of-type").attr("data-title");
    $(document).prop('title', HTMLtitle);
    document.title = HTMLtitle;
    // Used for popState event (back/forward browser buttons)
    changedPage = true;   }
```

The callback on my google maps API script call appears to properly initialize the map if page is loaded directly. If page is loaded by AJAX that doesn't work so I added the line **initMap();** there to load the map after the new content is loaded via AJAX.

This is working, but throwing an error and I'm worried that this error is causing other script on my page not to work properly.

**Any ideas on how to modify this so that the map initializes regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or by AJAX, and doesn't create any JS errors? Thanks!**

Comment: You have other errors too (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?target=api&ev=api_viewport&cad=hos…618x0.00921,size:858x720,relsize:0.64,token:404s4ux4j2,src:apiv3,ts:7ti0fd Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the error when I switched from the http://dma.nz/practice/ page to http://dma.nz/projects/ page.

As I can see you try to initialize map instance in line 82 of your map.js. The problem here is missing element with id "google-map". You don't have any DOM element with id "google-map" when you load the projects page. So you try to pass null in map constructor.

To avoid this error add a check that DOM element with id "google-map" exists.

```
// Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
var mapElement = document.getElementById('google-map');

if (mapElement) {
    // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    // Add marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: '/img/icons/map-pin.svg',
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.858749, 174.754944),
        map: map,
        title: 'DMA'
    });  
}
```

Comment: Yes this was the solution. So obvious I can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks you got +50.